# Persistent Terminal Session in Python

Tags: python, linux

I may not at all understand this correctly, but I am trying to allow a Python program to interface with a subprocess that runs commands as if on a Linux shell.

For example, I want to be able to run "cd /" and then "pwd later in the program and get "/".

I am currently trying to use subprocess.Popen and the communicate() method to send and receive data.  The first command, sent with the Popen constructor, runs fine and gives proper output.  But I cannot send another command via communicate(input="pwd").

My code so far:

```
from subprocess i
term=Popen("pwd", stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
print(flush(term.communicate()))
term.communicate(input="cd /")
print(flush(term.communicate(input="pwd")))
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks.

Also, I am running Python 3.

Comment: Use the `os.chdir` method.

Comment: So does that mean that I have to make a new Popen object for each command?

Comment: Not really. But In this case `pwd` just prints its output and exits immediatly. There is not a running process to communicate with. You do need to use fork/exec for each command, the normal shell behavior unless a pipeline is being built. In that case you do need a Popen for every command.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that running a shell command and running a program aren't the same thing.

Let me give you an example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['/bin/echo', '$HOME'])
$HOME
0
>>> subprocess.call(['/bin/echo $HOME'], shell=True)
/home/kkinder
0
```

Notice that without the shell=True parameter, the text of `$HOME` is not expanded. That's because the `/bin/echo` program doesn't parse `$HOME`, Bash does. What's really happening in the second call is something analogous to this:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-c', '/bin/echo $HOME'])
/home/kkinder
0
```

Using the `shell=True` parameter basically says to the subprocess module, *go interpret this text using a shell*.

So, you could add `shell=True`, but then the problem is that once the command finishes, its state is lost. Each application in the stack has its own working directory. So what the directory is will be something like this:

- bash - /foo/bar

  - python - /foo

    - bash via subprocess - /

After your command executes, the python process's path stays the same and the subprocess's path is discarded once the shell finishes your command.

Basically, what you're asking for isn't practical. What you would need to do is, open a pipe to Bash, interactively feed it commands your user types, then read the output in a non-blocking way. That's going to involve a complicated pipe, threads, etc. Are you sure there's not a better way?